# why does MQTT use less battery than Websockets+protobuf (or it doesnt?)

Tags: tcp, websocket, mqtt

While using a MQTT server a question popped up in my head, would it be better to use Protobuf+Websockets in my case?

I am making an instant messaging platform... clientA to server to database and clientB.

information that will be sent: conversation ID and message.

Comment: You've not really supplied enough context to give a full answer but I'll try.

Answer (score 2):

When you include the size of the HTTP header in the initial GET request and then the UPGRADE request to the server to start a Websocket connection the total network traffic is normally orders of magnitude more that of opening a MQTT connection and subscribing to a topic.

Sending data over the network uses the radio, which burns through battery, so the more data you send the more battery you burn. With MQTT more of the data sent and received is your actual payload and not the extra associated with the protocol.

While the difference caused by the initial handshake will even out for longer more stable connections as more data is sent/received, this is not always the case for mobile applications which tend to drop network connections more frequently as they move from 4G to 3G when moving between cell sites or switching between mobile data and WiFi.

Websockets are way better than HTTP long polling, but there is still that large initial network hit on the start of a connection.

Comment: is mqtt transferred as plain text?

Comment: You can do MQTT over SSL. The SSL handshake will be the same for both

Answer (score 1):

MQTT with compression / protobuf => best

MQTT => good

Websockets over HTTP with compression / protobuf => ok

Websockets over HTTP => so so

Only use Websockets if using something like JavaScript on the client side or if you want to be going over HTTP (e.g. to traverse firewalls more easily).